# Unable to read S3 bucket since upgrading to 2.4.4 and EMR 5.29

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Been recently trying to load Parquet files within my local Spark environment. Recently updated my EMR cluster to the latest version (previously using Spark 2.3.0) to Spark 2.4.4 in its latest EMR 5.29.

However, when I modify the versioning within my project to read the bucket using `s3a` the following prompts while debugging.

`org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on mybucket com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: : Failed to connect to service endpoint:`

The following dependencies are the ones being used.

```
    val spark          = "2.4.4"
    val awsSdk         = "1.11.682"
```

Another issue is that when using the older versioning (Spark 2.3.0), I wasn't able to read newly generated data as something in the serialization was updated (unable to parse Scala Array or List to whatever the new class Spark is using internally is).

Comment: What is the question you want answered?

Comment: @Zack the one referring to the failure when trying to connect to S3.